# Magmi Image Upload Remore Url from PHP

Tags: php, magento, magmi

Trying to upload image with magmi from url.

Does not work. Image not visible in back and frontend.

Really only code, tried everything not working, images also not work when using http.

```
 $newProductData = array(
        'name'          => (string)$v[title],        // name
        'sku'           => (string)$v[manufacturer_item_id],        // sku
        'special_price' => ((real)$v[recommended_retail_price]),    // special price        
        'price'         => ((real)$v[recommended_retail_price]),    // price
        'attribute_set' => 'Fahrrad',            // attribute_set
        'type'          => 'configurable',
        'store'         => 'admin',            
        'description'   => (string)$v[title],        // full description
        'short_description' => (string)$v[title],    // short description
        'qty'           => (string) 10,        // qty
        'category_ids'    => $v[category],                // ID of categories
        'weight'        => (string) '',        // weight
        'tax_class_id'  => '2',                    // tax class id (check your ids)
        'manufacturer'    => (string) $v[manufacturer_name],        // manufacturer
        'meta_title' =>   (string) $v[title],            // meta title
        'meta_description' => (string)$v[title],    // meta description
        'meta_keyword' => (string)$v[title]      // meta keywords
);
$newProductData['image']='+'.(string)'http://www.velo-zuerich.ch/velo-zuerich-bilder/velo-news/kettenlos-700C-Curve-velo.jpg';        // + show picture, - dont show picture
$newProductData['small_image']='+'.(string)'http://www.velo-zuerich.ch/velo-zuerich-bilder/velo-news/kettenlos-700C-Curve-velo.jpg';            // small img
$newProductData['thumbnail']='+'.(string)'http://www.velo-zuerich.ch/velo-zuerich-bilder/velo-news/kettenlos-700C-Curve-velo.jpg';            // thumbnail
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($newProductData);
//echo "</pre>";
$dp->ingest($newProductData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the **Image attributes processor** plugin enabled, which is required for Magmi to import images.

Also make sure you set the **Pre-download check for remote images** to **Enable** for the Image attributes processor config.

Lastly, check your Magmi log file and see what Magmi is outputting.  If the images are not importing, Magmi will usually produce an error or warning describing why in it's log.